# Filter image list based on cloud-init flag value

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Could you guide me, how to list a public images with filters like "cloud-init" and creation time through soft layer java sdk?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the Java api client does not support Object Filters.

There is an issue reported about this, see below:

https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-java/issues/30

You could use another supported programming language for filters like python or use a Rest call.

Regards.

Comment: we could not able to retrieve the cloud-init flag along with image group while fetching a image template list.

using below API to fetch the image list,
Group.Service service = Group.service(client);
List<Group> listGroups = service.getPublicImages();

can you please help me, how to get the cloud-inti flag along with group object.